# magento mail not sending

Tags: php, email, magento, magento-1.9

Try block for email sending is working, but it directly redirect to another page without sending mail. `smtp` setting are okay. This code was working perfectly but now nothing is happening.

```
try{ ..........................................//mail senting
    $this->_initLayoutMessages('customer/session');
    $this->_initLayoutMessages('catalog/session');

    //get customer details
    $customer = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer();
    $customer->getId();
    $customer->getEmail();

    //get general store details
    $from_name = Mage::getStoreConfig('trans_email/ident_general/name');
    $from_email = Mage::getStoreConfig('trans_email/ident_general/email');


    $templateId=7;
    $emailTemplate = Mage::getModel('core/email_template')->load($templateId);
    //$emailTemplateVariables = array();
    //$emailTemplateVariables[‘name′] = "$mh"";


    $processedTemplate = $emailTemplate->getProcessedTemplate();

    $mail=Mage::getModel('core/email');
    $mail->setToName($customer->getId());
    $mail->setToEmail($customer->getEmail());
    $mail->setBody($processedTemplate);
    $mail->setSubject("Upload Conformation ");
   // print_r($mail);
    //die;
    $mail->setFromEmail($from_email);
    $mail->setFromName($from_name);

    $mail->setType('html'); 
    try {
        $mail->send();
        Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addSuccess('Your request has been sent');


        } catch (Exception $e) {
            Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addError('Unable to send.');
        }


       Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getResponse()->setRedirect(Mage::getBaseUrl().'bank-info/'); 

    } catch (Exception $ex) {
        Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addError($ex->getMessage());
        Mage::log($ex->getMessage());
        Mage::getSingleton("supplierfrontendproductuploader/session")->setProductData($postData);

        if($editMode) {
            Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getResponse()->setRedirect(Mage::getBaseUrl() . 'supplierfrontendproductuploader/product/edit/id/'.$postData['product_id']);
        } else {
            Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getResponse()->setRedirect(Mage::getBaseUrl() . 'supplierfrontendproductuploader/product/create/');
        }
```

Comment: Are you using 1.9.1?  All email sending has been offloaded to the cron system - core_email_queue_send_all

Comment: In the server part it is showing as pending." (12)Cannot allocate memory: couldn't create child process: /opt/suphp/sbin/suphp"...is showing in error log

Comment: Sounds like an APC issue.  Restart apache.